# Python Script for sending mail returns no errors but mail not received

Tags: python, smtp

Using my gmail account as a test for sending mail using python.  It appears the mail is getting sent (or at least passes over the mail server) but it is not being received.  I cannot seem to find any logs that would allow me to trace the email (Using Linux Mint 20).  First question is where can I find these logs?  Secondly, does anything in this script seem incorrect?  Please assume that the `data` is correctly populated.  My gmail account is set to allow less secure apps as well.

```
with open("config.json",) as config:
        data = json.load(config)                
        smtp_server = data["MAIL"]["SMTP_SERVER"]
        port = data["MAIL"]["SMTP_PORT"]
        sender_email = data["MAIL"]["SMTP_ACCOUNT"]
        password = data["MAIL"]["SMTP_PASSWORD"]
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)        
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls(context=context)
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(sender_email,password)                
            return server
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return None
```

Comment: Is the email in your account's outbox?

Comment: They are all in the Sent folder on my gmail account.

Comment: So this part of the code worked. The next step would be to review the message itself. You could download from gmail to an eml file. Look at it as text and verify the email address and headers. Then use the `email` module to read it. `msg = email.message_from_file(open("somename.eml"))` and see if you can read any mime attachments. But if the target server thinks this is spam or malware, it will discard the message silently.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @tdelaney.  Can't send email to yourself with gmail.

Comment: `server.send_mail` returns a value, you should check its contents.